# Cannot explicitly hide variable member even using "new" keyword

Tags: unity, c#

> [See the answer by me](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/154614/50756), this problem is pretty much my own mistakes of miss understandings.

So, here is my problem.

I have parent class called `CameraBehaviour` derived from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)

```
public class CameraBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MinMax CameraViewRange;

    private Single CalculateViewRange() { ... }
}
```

and have two class `ActionCamera2D` and `ActionCamera3D` derived from `CameraBehaviour`

```
public class ActionCamera2D : CameraBehaviour
{
    [MinMaxRange (2f, 5f)]
    public new MinMax CameraViewRange = new MinMax(2f, 5f);
}

public class ActionCamera3D : CameraBehaviour
{
    [MinMaxRange(20f, 50f)]
    public new MinMax CameraViewRange = new MinMax(20f, 50f);
}
```

as you can see, both the script has `CameraViewRange` with `new` keyword and has different `MinMaxRange` attribute attached on each script, so the limit is will be vary between this script but still using the same `CalculateViewRange` calculation as the parent script.

But it turns out to be not possible, in [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) at least, raising an error:

```
The same field name is serialized multiple times in the class or its parent class.
This is not supported: Base(MonoBehaviour) CameraViewRange
```

- `MinMaxRange` is a custom written attribute for property drawer.
- `MinMax` is a custom struct that store min and max value.

  1. > - <s>So, how can I overcome / deal with this problem ?</s>
     > - No, you can't, it's the C# design pattern to prevent that.
  2. > - <s>Is my code pattern here is **`wrong`** ?</s>
     > - Yes.
  3. > - <s>Is there any workaround or better solutions for this ?</s>
     > - [See the answer by me](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/154614/50756).
  4. > - <s>Or is this the C# and Unity limitations ?</s>
     > - It's just the C# and Unity Inspector design pattern.

thanks

Comment: Maybe implement `CameraBehaviour::CameraViewRange` as `virtual` and `override` it on both `ActionCamera2D` and `ActionCamera3D`?

Comment: @OnoSendai unfortunately no, `C#` can't set field as a virtual, AFAIK only functions can be virtual, with that being said, I was thinking to remove the `CameraViewRange` from `CameraBehaviour` and mark the `CalculateViewRange()` as virtual and override it from the child class, It's possible, but the problem is ( well maybe it's not a problem ), both the `ActionCamera2D` and `ActionCamera3D` use the same calculation, and having two same calculation on different class seems out of OOP context.

Comment: You're right, my comment was incomplete. Can you set CameraViewRange as an auto-implemented virtual property (`public virtual MinMax CameraViewRange {get; set;}`)

Comment: You tried to make CameraViewRange a property and rename its corresponding variable between the parent and the sub (and make them private serializable through [SerializeField])?

Comment: @OnoSendai it's possible, but my property drawer have some problem with property so can't set the value on Unity inspector

Comment: @Nikaas yeah, that's the problem, altho I want to try doing some reflection to perform that, even tho I know the possibilities are low.

Comment: @Nikaas I was trying to add the [MinMaxAttribute] to the field so it's render in the Inspector, and as you can see the value between `2D` and `3D` are different, Actually, I can remove this and just Inherit the class *normally* and not doing anything, but I just want to make sure that the variable have range between a and b without changing the original field that used in parent class for calculation.

Comment: I'm missing something. Why do you care for the name to be the same?

Comment: @Nikaas because the field is used by the parent class for do the calculation, the child class just merely the value limiter.

Answer (score 1):

Well after hours of debugging and searching other solutions, I think it's not possible to do that, I've encountered using `[NonSerializedAttribute]` and `[SerializeFieldAttribute]` but the behaviour is changed as it seems to be different instance with same name.

so the solution ?

1. > - Remove the field from parent class.
   > - Convert the `CalculateViewRange()` into `virtual`.

code :

```
public class CameraBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected virtual Single CalculateViewRange() { }
}

public class ActionCamera2D : CameraBehaviour
{
    [MinMaxRange (2f, 5f)]
    public MinMax CameraViewRange = new MinMax(2f, 5f);

    protected override Single CalculateViewRange() { CameraRangeCalculation }
}

public class ActionCamera3D : CameraBehaviour
{
    [MinMaxRange (20f, 50f)]
    public MinMax CameraViewRange = new MinMax(20f, 50f);

    protected override Single CalculateViewRange() { CameraRangeCalculation }
}
```

2. > - Remove the field from child class.
   > - Basically, just give up about the limiting range feature, it seems not possible.

code :

```
public class CameraBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MinMax CameraViewRange;
    private Single CalculateViewRange() { }
}

public class ActionCamera2D : CameraBehaviour
{
    ...
    // 2D Specific Functions
    ...
}

public class ActionCamera3D : CameraBehaviour
{
    ...
    // 3D Specific Functions
    ...
}
```

3. > Bonus If you need this not paricularly for Unity / Unity Inspector / Unity Editor, you can use Property with the same name and then explicitly declare the `get; set;` to update the parent's field value.

code :

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public Single FooBar;

    private Single MultiplyFooBarBy2()
    {
        return this.FooBar * 2;
    }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public Single FooBar
    {
        get => base.FooBar;
        set => base.FooBar = value;
    }
}

// OR which is possibly compatible with Unity Inspector [using attributes]

public abstract class ParentClass
{
    protected abstract Single FooBar { get; set; }

    private Single MultiplyFooBarBy2()
    {
        return this.FooBar * 2;
    }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    //[Range (0f, 1f)] // Untested, but should do
    public Single FieldOfFooBar;

    protected override Single FooBar
    {
        get => this.FieldOfFooBar;
        set => this.FieldOfFooBar = value;
    }
}
```

EDIT :

> Well I should've realized that it's not possible at the very begining. 
>   You can't override fields. And expecting the parent will get the child's value.